# Django with Postgresql update object, prevent order re-ordering

Tags: django, postgresql

in django production mode with postgreSQL, When I got an still existing object/row from the database, edit/update it and store it back, the row is moved to the end of the table.

- object 1
- object 2
- object 3

**after done editing object 1**

- object 2
- object 3
- object 1

**models.py**

```
class itemModels(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.ImageField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="default.png")
    photo2 = models.ImageField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="default2.png")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __self__(self):
    return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
class itemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = itemModels.objects.all()
    serializer = itemSerializers()
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'product-list.html'
    lookup_field = 'pk'

    # list all item
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = itemModels.objects.all()
        context = {'posts': queryset}
        return Response(context)

    # serializer form
    def serializer_list(self, request):
        serializer = itemSerializers()
        return Response({'serializer': serializer}, template_name='product-create.html')

    def retrieve(self, request, pk):
        profile = get_object_or_404(itemModels, pk=pk)
        serializer = itemSerializers(profile)
        return Response({'serializer': serializer}, template_name='product-edit.html')

    def update(self, request, pk):
        profile = get_object_or_404(itemModels, pk=pk)
        serializer = itemSerializers(profile, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            print('status: status.Item Update')
            return redirect('item')
        else:
            print('status: status.Item Bad Update')
```

i want to prevent this re-ordering happen, is there something i miss out ? thanks guys

Note:
if i am using development mode and switch the to django dummie database, this wont happen.

Comment: It's probably better to specify an explicit order for your queries than to rely on the order of rows in the table.

Comment: @snakecharmerb do you mean, i need to post my postgrasql database row ?

Comment: No, I mean you you do queries something like this: `queryset = itemModels.objects.order_by('name').all()`.   That is, if you want objects in a particular order, specify the order with `order_by`.  The database can order its tables in anyway it pleases, and you have no guarantee that third party software like the serialiser isn't doing a delete and insert rather than an update.

Answer (score 0):

```
def list(self, request):
    queryset = itemModels.objects.all()
    context = {'posts': queryset}
    return Response(context)
```

to

```
def list(self, request):
    queryset = itemModels.objects.order_by('id').all()
    context = {'posts': queryset}
    return Response(context)
```

credit for @snakecharmerb thanks